# Resources for C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to C++ Templates, and am finding it hard to understand and debug them.  What are some good resources for doing both/either?

Comment: They're pretty simple. Give us a code you don't understand, we'll try to figure it out together.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you need to know about them, and what don't you understand?

Comment: What material have you read and not understood? There's plenty of good books and online texts that explain templates.

Comment: I'd recommend a look at the introductory book by Alexandrescu on the subject: "Modern C++ Design" ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend the excellent book [C++ Templates - The Complete Guide](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/tmplbook.html) by Vandevoorde and Josuttis.

Answer (score 4):

[Alexandrescu](http://erdani.org/publications/) is a wizard of templates. He has a lot of write-ups (many of which is freely available on his web-site and other sites) and some books.

Boost [Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/) and [Boost Cookbook](http://www.boostcookbook.com/) is a good site to start with once you are comfortable with templates and feel like graduating to Boost.

Answer (score 1):

A template is simply a way of reducing the amount of code you need to write when developing classes.

For example the STL vector

```
std::vector<int> intList;
std::vector<float> floatList;
```

This will cause the compiler to actually make two classes behind the scenes, similar to if you copy and pasted the code but replaced all references to int with float.

Without templates you would need to create a vector class for each type you want to handle. There are more complex uses for classes but this is the easiest one to use, create & understand.

Once compiled the two sets of code for `vector<int>` and `vector<float>` are completely separate, but an IDE will step through the template class when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I have two quick tips that may save you some problems in the future.

**Templates must be defined and implemented in headers, because they are translated/created at compile-time**

If you have the following code:

```
// Foo.h
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    ...
};

// Bar.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
void func()
{
    Foo<int> fooInt;
    Foo<double> fooDouble;
}
```

When processing the Bar.cpp file, the compiler will "create" a new definition of the Foo class with every T replaced with the int type for the fooInt instance, and a new definition of the Foo class with every T replaced with the double type for the fooDouble instance.

In a nutshell, C++ does not support template classes, the compiler emulates them replacing the types at compile time and creating normal classes. So, the compiled type of fooInt and fooDouble are different.

Because they are translated at compile-time and not compiled individually, they *must* be defined and implemented in headers.

If you implement the template class as a normal class (header and source file) the error thrown by the compiler (the linker actually) is that there is no method implemented (it's because the source file is ignored).

**You can still create forward declarations to avoid cyclic dependencies**

It's just that you have to forward declare them like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo;
```

And, as with normal forward declarations, you have to be sure that you are including all the headers necessary.

Answer (score 0):

They are there for you to extend and modify as needed.  Remember, it's a template, not a solution.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

this is a very good and nearly concise article to learn about c++ templates
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

I will bring essential parts in here:

**1.function templates:**

simple function template:

```
template<class TYPE>
void PrintTwice(TYPE data)
{
    cout<<"Twice: " << data * 2 << endl;
}
```

note that "TYPE" can be any other valid name.

> You should better use a name that reflects the meaning of type-parameter, and that improves code readability.

now you can call it like this:

```
PrintTwice(5.5);//TYPE is 'float'
PrintTwice(5);//TYPE is 'int'
```

you can force the compiler to instantiate the function for the type you pass explicitly:

```
PrintTwice<double>(5);
```

if you don't pass any type, compiler determines what the type is.

you can have templates of multiple arguments and(optionally) return type same type:

```
template<class T>
T Add(T n1, T n2)
{
    return n1 + n2;
}
```

but note that you cant for example pass `n1` in `int` and `n2` in double! both arguments should be of the same type and return type is also of that type.

if you want to have a template function of possibly different type argument:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
double Add(T1 t1Data, T2 t2Data)
{
     return t1Data + t2Data;
}
```

and use it like:

```
cout<<Add(5,7.0);//T1=int T2=double
cout<<Add(5.5,7);//T1=double T2=int
cout<<Add<double,double>(5,7);//T1=double T2=double by passing types explicitly
```

When function-template takes template-type, but not from its function arguments like:

```
template<class T>
void PrintSize()
{
   cout << "Size of this type:" << sizeof(T);
}
```

You cannot call such function template simply as:

```
PrintSize();
```

Since this function template would require template type argument specification, and it cannot be deduced automatically by compiler. The correct call would be:

```
PrintSize<float>();
```

**2.class templates:**

definition is almost similar:

```
template<class T>
class Item
{
    T Data;
public:
    Item() : Data( T() )
    {}

    void SetData(T nValue)
    {
        Data = nValue;
    }

    T GetData() const
    {
        return Data;
    }

    void PrintData()
    {
        cout << Data;
    }
};
```

but when using it, you should specify the type explicitly:

```
Item<int> item1;
```

the tricky part is, you can not implement declarations in header file, and the respective implementation in one or more source files.(please refer to article to see why)

class templates also allow few non-type template arguments:

```
template<class T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
 static const int Elements_2x = SIZE * 2;
void DoSomething(int arg = SIZE); 
// Non-const can also appear as default-argument...
private:
   T TheArray[SIZE];
};
```

there is so many other parts and a lot lot more explanation which i can not bring here.

i suggest you spend a few hours and read that article and second part of that article. even if you think you know how templates work in c++.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: It's also a good idea not to answer off-topic questions, such as requests for off-site resources.